# setOnKeyListener in EditText

Tags: android, android-view

I using setOnKeyListener on a EditText with named Search. Everything just work fine, but when I try to press on the EditText twice, its bring me to next EditText. How can I avoid this?

```
    search.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) { 
                // Perform action on key press          


                  return true;
               }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the value in the EditText is not null and perform the action

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake in XML file. the second EditText should not included

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ET2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ET1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ET1"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:ems="10" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```